# Waiting for AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my application I need to download some data from 2 different urls, and then populate a list. To do so I create one 2 AsyncTask classes. The first class is responsible for downloading the data from the corresponding url. The other one is responsible for executing the aforementioned asyncTasks and after that populating a list on the UI thread. I need the tasks that download data to be run in parallel so I execute them on the executor. My problem is that the task that is responsible for populating the list terminates before the other two tasks download the data. How can I make that thread wait for the other two to return. I should use .get on the others because i need them to run in parallel. I'm also posting some code in order to be clear.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                          readJsonTask task = new readJsonTask(this);


          task.execute();
    }

      private class readJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

              downloadUrl task = new downloadUrl(url1,"jsonData1","/sdcard/appData/LocalJson/jsonData1");
              task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

              downloadUrl task1 = new downloadUrl(url2,"jsonData2","/sdcard/appData/LocalJson/jsonData2");
              task1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

             return "done"; 

      }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //update UI

        }
    }


      private class downloadUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String url;
        private String targetFolder;
        private String pathForLoad;



            @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {               


            //download Data


            return "done"; 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               



        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Handler to dispatch a message once both tasks have completed or you could update the UI after each async task completes.

Also if you're referring to a thread which is referring to the main thread, you could make it wait but this is NOT the preferred method.

### Options 1 (Psuedo code)

```
// The code here will dispatch a message which will tell the handler
// to attempt and update, however; the handler will only process it
// if both options have complete their work then reset their state

boolean mJob1complete
boolean mJob2complete

AsyncTask(1)
{
 When finished
 mJob1complete = true;
 dispatch(message)
}

AsyncTask(2)
{
 When finished
 mJob2complete = true;
 dispatch(message)
}

Handler()
{
 onMessage()
 if(mJob1complete && mjob2complete)
 {
  udpateui // Make sure to run this update on the ui thread with something like runOnUiThread()
  // reset state
  mJob1complete = false;
  mJob2complete = false;
 }
}
```

### Option 2

In order to have a message dispatched once BOTH tasks complete, the solution to that would be to organize your AsyncTasks and have a manager that would be aware of the current state of each asynctask and once both complete then dispatch a message similar to above.

### Option 3

Just update the UI after each AsyncTask completes, this would be much easier and cleaner because then you don't have to maintain states.

Comment: well i like the second approach, however can you post some code explaining how the first would work?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `readJsonTask`. Instead start your `downloadUrl` tasks in the `onCreate` method (or wherever you think is more appropriate) and in `downloadUrl`'s `onPostExecute` update that part of the UI that is related to the fetched json.